# Expression Engine Channel relationship field not showing

Tags: channel-entries, relationships, channel-form

I have a channel "Page".

In the page channel, I have following fields where `{assign_parent_page}` is a relationship field http://puu.sh/81UAe.png that I have made so as I can assign the channel entry as sub entry for another channel entry. I.e In the PAGE channel, if i have suppose 10 enteries, I want that entry 2 to be a sub entry for entry 1. So, in to obtain this, I made a relationship field ("For eg: sub page in WORDPRESS")
**http://puu.sh/81Ul5.png**

```
{title}
{page_body}
{page_title_image}
{page_sidebar_check}
{assign_parent_page}
```

In my template, I am using this code as

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="page"}
   {assign_parent_page}
      {assign_parent_page:title}
   {/assign_parent_page}
   {title}
   {page_body}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

But the output , I am getting is http://puu.sh/81UqV.jpg **{assign_parent_page} {assign_parent_page:title} {/assign_parent_page}**

Can anyone please help me how to display a relationship field.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't look like your regular title and page_body are showing up. Are you sure that your channel entries tags are outputting correctly?

Comment: Yes, title and body are showing up correctly. Infact, all other fields are showing except the {assign_parent_page}

Comment: Is you relationship field single or multiple?